# Qt: how to apply a shortcut( Key_Comma + Key_Return) to action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, qt, qkeysequence

I tried to set a shortcut by the following code, but it doesn't work. If I change it to ALT + Comma or ALT + Return, it will be fine. but the request is Comma + Return. Does anyone know how to set this special shortcut on Qt?

```
    @shotcut = Qt::Shortcut.new(Qt::KeySequence.new(Qt::Key_Comma + 
    Qt::Key_Return), self, SLOT('save_by_shortcut()'))
    @shotcut.setEnabled(true)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: try like this: `Qt::KeySequence.new(Qt::Key_Comma, Qt::Key_Return)`

Answer (score 0):

You can create it by using the multiple arguments constructor for [QKeySequence](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qkeysequence.html).

like this:

```
auto ac = new QAction(this);
ac->setShortcut(Qt::Key_Comma + Qt::Key_Return);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I just try it it turns out to be like #<Qt::KeySequence:0x0000000c4cc140 Ctrl+K, Ctrl+C>. what I want to achieve is only comma + enter which without Ctrl.